# How to stop VM and Validate that VM is stoped using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

For my Project, I need to create an Ansible script that does the following:

1. Shut down VM
2. Checks that vm are not reachable
3. Create messages that say what VM is still up and what vm is still down.

I wrote the following script for this:

```
---
# tasks file for start-stop-vm
- name: Stop all VM
  community.general.shutdown:
    # delay: 60
  when: ('webservers' in group_names)

- name: check what vm is still up
  ansible.builtin.ping:
  register: result

# - name: Output result
#   debug:
#     var: result

- name: Return the vm that still running
  debug:
    msg: "Following VM are still up {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: (result.failed == false)


- name: Return the vm that still running
  debug:
    msg: "Following VM are down {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: (result.failed != false)
```

My question is, is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a VMware-based VM? if that's the case, you can use the vmware modules:

```
       - name: "Shuting down using guest tools"
          vmware_guest_powerstate:
            hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
            username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
            password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
            validate_certs: False
            uuid: "{{ vm_facts.instance.hw_product_uuid }}"
            state: shutdown-guest
            state_change_timeout: 240
            force: yes
          delegate_to: "localhost"
          register: newState
          ignore_errors: yes
          when: vm_facts.instance.guest_tools_status == "guestToolsRunning"

        - name: "Power off from vCenter"
          vmware_guest_powerstate:
            hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
            username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
            password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
            validate_certs: False
            uuid: "{{ vm_facts.instance.hw_product_uuid }}"
            state: powered-off
            force: yes
          delegate_to: "localhost"
          ignore_errors: yes
          register: newState
```

- First task tries to poweroff the VM using guest tools
- Second task tries to poweroff the VM using the poweroff option from VMWare.

After this two steps, you can get current status for the VM to confirm that the actual state is powered off.